# Password and phone number validation

Tags: android, regex, validation

Let us suppose that you want the following in the edit text fields. What regex would you use?

[image: validation]

For the email I used this:

```
if(!email.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+")) {
    etEmail.setError("Invalid Email Address");
}
```

But how do I go about with the others?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would you call a special character?

Comment: How many QAs do you find if you search StackOveflow for "password regex" and for "phone number regex" ? Please explain for each of them, why it does not help you, I cannot find anything in your question which makes it different enough from the others. So I do not really understand the specific problem you have. I.e. your question is unclear to me.

Comment: @Theo I've finished my answer, feel free to refer to it, and point out any specification of yours that it may not have met :)

Comment: [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/48346033#48346033) may really benefit you

Answer (score 2):

For the password, you could try:

```
if(!(password.length() >= 6) || !password.matches(".*?[A-Z].*") || !password.matches(".*?[a-z].*") || !password.matches(".*?[0-9].*") || !password.matches(".*?[\\W\\-_].*")) {
    System.out.println("Password Invalid");
}
```

## Explanation -

```
.*? - indicates that the regex may start with zero-or-more characters, before being followed by<br>
    [A-Z]     - a Capital Letter from 'A' to 'Z'
    [a-z]     - a lowercase letter from 'a' to 'z'
    [0-9]     - a digit from 0-9
    [\\W\\-_] - a non-word character (not letter, digit or dash), a dash, or underscore
.* - indicates that after the special character (or whatever the requirement for that condition is), there may be zero-or-more characters.
```

This approach may seem a bit lengthy, but is certainly easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

for name :-  if(!name.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]")){
//show error here}

for email :  if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches()){
/show error here}

for mobile :- if(mobile.length<10){
//show error here }